# Should IndexOutOfBoundsException be checked?

Tags: java

I recently tracked down a bug where a list was of length 0 but an access attempt was made at position 1

```
System.out.println("key is " + keyValuesPairs.get(0)+ " , value is " + keyValuesPairs.get(1));
```

This caused an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` but because it was not caught the exception is silently dropped and no indication is made that an exception is thrown. For this reason should `IndexOutOfBoundsException` be a checked exception as it can cause difficult to find bugs ?

Update : the exception is not silently dropped.

Comment: If you did catch it, what would you do about it?

Comment: Silently dropped from what call? Ajax, EJB?

Comment: Why would it be silently dropped? Unchecked exceptions should be rippling out and generate stack traces.

Comment: IndexOutOfBoundsException is not dropped silently.

Comment: This probably isn't a good fit for SO. Checked vs. Unchecked exceptions are controversial enough that there's a section devoted to it in the Java docs: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/runtime.html

Comment: You can add a size check idiom in your programming before accessing a data-structure

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis log a message that indicates an access attempt for a non-existent address space, or similar to the effect

Comment: This seems like a: "Does this code make my ass look fat?" type of question.

Comment: It doesn't 'cause difficult to find bugs'. It *reports*  bugs that would *otherwise* be difficult to find. The problem isn't the exception: the problem is your invalid code.

Comment: Practically speaking, if IndexOutOfBoundsException were "checked", virtually all methods would have to declare it thrown.  (In practice, "unchecked" exceptions are exceptions that are so ubiquitous that there's no point in declaring them.)

Comment: Simply put, you don't know what you're talking about.  An unchecked exception is not silently ignored (by the system) -- it will bring your app down just as surely as a checked exception.  If the exception is being ignored it's due to your code (or the code of some 3rd party which you're using without knowing its quality).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is not *Should I catch this exception?* it is *Why is this exception being consumed unreported?*.

There is indeed a fault in the code but the other fault - the hidden one that is quietly consuming your exception and discarding it - is a much more pernicious error.

This is why

```
...
} catch (Exception e) {
  // Ignore it.
}
```

is **almost always** a code smell.

Comment: And note that simply _logging_ it is also ignoring it.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis - Logging it without rethrowing it.

Answer (score 2):

No I shouldn't be catched. It's a runtime exception see this link for more details : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/runtime.html

What you can do is testing on the index you are using against the array length

Answer (score 1):

I would not catch that exception. Instead I would simply check the bounds like this:

```
if(keyValuesPairs.size() > 0) {...}
```

Answer (score 1):

You already answered the question:

"I recently tracked down a bug where a list was of length 0 but an access attempt was made at position 1."

It is a bug in the code - you need to resolve the issue where it's even possible for an index larger than array can be used.  There's a reason this isn't a checked exception (meaning Java does not require you to catch it).  And that reason is you cannot possibly know why an incorrect index was used when the error occurs, and cannot gracefully recover from it.

You should fix the bug you found and not catch the exception.  Make it so the exception no longer is thrown.

Answer (score 1):

All `RuntimeException`s are things that ideally, should never need to happen. They are caused when a program is not sufficiently careful with regard to the unknown, and tries to do things that no sane method should ever consider, and with objects and methods they have only the shallowest glimpse of.

Sometimes, a method is unwittingly tricked into attempting something it shouldn't, by a nefarious master who forces them to take a `null` or empty array, even though the method's documentation indicate it is unqualified to handle such things. But worse still, when the master gets word that their schemes failed, some will try to cover up their failure, by intercepting the exception before it can reach its superiors, corrupting the system with laziness and sloppiness. Even when the master has a suitable way to deal with their failure, they still waste the extra resources and processing power caused by the disorder.

The moral of the story: don't write bad code.

Answer (score 0):

It should not be checked, because if it will be checked then the `List` interface and others needs to change to add `throws` to methods that would be overkill.

The exceptions like `IndexOutOfBoundsException` or `NullPointerException` should be prevented before they are thrown. These exceptions are `RuntimeException` that could be occurred when application is run depending on data and not intentionally. The circumstances in which these exceptions occur are unpredictable and cannot say if the code throws exception or not. That's why it should be runtime exceptions.

In you code, to be a valid code, you should check the bounds of index before you use an arbitrary index to access elements of the list. Use `isEmpty()` or `size()` to get the condition in which you should correct the flow.